# What is wron with this MySQL join query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a breaks and clock_in_out table and I want to get the all values from both and join them on their user_id column. But I am getting incorrect synatx to use near JOIN ON, not a clue why.. Here is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `breaks` 
WHERE `user_id` = 1 
AND `in_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `out_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
JOIN `clock_in_out` ON `breaks`.`user_id` = `clock_in_out`.`user_id` 
WHERE `loggedin_date` 
LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `loggedout_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%'
```

Comment: where clauses should be after your joins

Comment: Not too familiar with MySQL but can you have 2 `WHERE` clauses - ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses like that. The order is: `SELECT`, `FROM`, `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `LIMIT`. So it should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `breaks` 
JOIN `clock_in_out` ON `breaks`.`user_id` = `clock_in_out`.`user_id` 
WHERE `user_id` = 1 
AND `in_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `out_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `loggedin_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `loggedout_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%'
```

See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for the complete syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE` clause should be after `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `breaks` JOIN 
     `clock_in_out` ON `breaks`.`user_id` = `clock_in_out`.`user_id`
WHERE `user_id` = 1 
  AND `in_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
  AND `out_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
  AND `loggedin_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
  AND `loggedout_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. The correct syntax for join is `Select ... from .. join ... on ... where`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `breaks` 
JOIN `clock_in_out` ON `breaks`.`user_id` = `clock_in_out`.`user_id` 
WHERE `loggedin_date` 
LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `loggedout_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%'
AND `user_id` = 1 
AND `in_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `out_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for the this is as follows

```
    SELECT * 
FROM `breaks` 
JOIN `clock_in_out` ON `breaks`.`user_id` = `clock_in_out`.`user_id` 
WHERE `user_id` = 1 
AND `in_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `out_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `loggedin_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%' 
AND `loggedout_date` LIKE '%2015-03-03%
```

Comment: Thanks guys! But this returns 1 result row, when there should be two sets of result